# Standard emacs lisp function for "collect-if"

Tags: filtering, iteration

Is there a standard emacs-lisp function replacement for

```el
(defun collect-if (PREDICATE LIST)
  (loop for el in LIST if (funcall PREDICATE el) collect el))
```

---

Example toy application: Extract the odd numbers from a list of numbers

```el
(collect-if (lambda (x) (/= 0 (% x 2))) '(1 2 3 4 5))
(1 3 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay `remove-if-not` makes a copy of the list it operates on. So this is the equivalent to `collect-if` above.

From my perspective `remove-if-not` is a really tricky name for something like `collect-if` or `sub-list` (**not** with the meaning of `cl-sublis` but with the meaning of sub-list). There should be an alias saying more directly what that function does.

Comment: I believe the current function name is the one used in Common Lisp.

Comment: @Dan This is almost clear since `remove-if-not` is from the `cl-seq` package. I am not saying the alias should live in `cl`. I think I put a remainder somewhere that I actually should use `remove-if-not` when I want `collect-if`.

Comment: BTW, the standard name for this is `filter` (or for the Smalltalkers/Rubyists among us, `select`).  dash.el provides both.  Rumor has it dash.el was invented in a fit of rage after finding out that elisp got blessed with the unwieldy `cl-remove-if-not` identifier...

Answer (score 2):

Emacs 25 [will include the `seq.el`](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/seq.el) library, which will provide default functions to manipulate sequences. Right now you can download it from GNU ELPA for Emacs 24. The functions you are looking for are:

```
(seq-filter (lambda (x) (/= 0 (% x 2))) '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; => (1 3 5)
(seq-remove (lambda (x) (/= 0 (% x 2))) '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; => (2 4)
```